# Mixing ImageCapture and non-ImageCapture constraints is not currently supported

Tags: javascript, webrtc, webapi, getusermedia

I have started learning webRtc. There I found **getUserMedia(*constraints*)** to display media(audio/video). So I decided to dig deep the constraints. So there is a function `getCapabilities()` which return all supported constraints for a track. So I decided to create dynamic control(audio/video) separately like below. And on change of each controls I am calling `applyConstraints(updatedConstraint)` to apply the constraints.
[image]

Things are working fine. But There is one issue. If I change the brightness first then I am not able to change aspectRatio/height/width or If I change height/width first then I am not able to change brightness/contrast. I am getting an error.
`Uncaught (in promise) OverconstrainedError: Mixing ImageCapture and non-ImageCapture constraints is not currently supported`

Later I found that for video track we have 2 types constraints. One is for the Image and second is for the Video track. So My question is

1. for video track how can we separate constraints for Image and Video dynamically. Because `getCapabilities()` does not return any flag.
2. Even If we separate those constraints then how can we avoid this error `Mixing ImageCapture and non-ImageCapture constraints is not currently supported`

`track.getCapabilities()` return data like below for video track
[image]

If required then I can paste my code as well.

Comment: Some remarks about this. 1) video capture resolution and aspect ratio are device-dependent.  2) every browser works a  bit differently. Mobile Safari (iPhones and iPads) is the least predictable. 3) changing captured resolution or aspect ratio often requires doing `getUserMedia()` again rather than `applyConstraints()`  4) the spotty implementation quality of all this constraint stuff means you'll hit this kind of trouble a lot.

Comment: @O.Jones  issue is not due to aspect ratio. It is because of video track. In video track we have 2 type of constrains(image and video). So If we use Video constrains `(like aspect ratio, frame Rate etc.)` Then we can not use Image constrains `(like saturation, contrast etc.)` and vice versa. But it is not giving any error when with audio track.

Comment: @IrshadKhan Were you able to solve this issue? I have it as well..

Comment: @O.Jones Thanks, calling `getUserMedia()` again with required resolution worked!